# Find a Syntax error in Python DNA Sequence

Tags: python

**Im getting a syntax error in line 5 // for k,v in // how can I solve this please?
i'm not sure what's the error here**

```
    alt_map = {'ins':'0'}
    complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}
    def reverse_complement(seq):
          for k,v in
       alt_map.iteritems():
                      seq = seq.replace(k,v)
              bases = list(seq)
              bases = reversed([complement.get(base,base) for base in bases])
               bases = ''.join(bases)
             for k,v in
                    alt_map.iteritems():
                bases = bases.replace(v,k) return bases
    >>> seq = "TCGGinsGCCC"
    >>> print "Reverse Complement:"
    >>> print(reverse_complement(seq))
    GGGCinsCCGA
    
    def ReverseComplement(Pattern):
         revcomp = [ ]
     x = len(Pattern)
     for i in Pattern:
         x = x - 1
         revcomp.append(Pattern[x])
      return ''.join(revcomp)
```

Comment: Try adding a backslash with a space ` \` after `for k,v in`.

Comment: And make sure your indentations line up!

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining)

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot do automatic line breaks inmidst of a command.
You have to do:

```
for k,v in \
```

- with `\` as explicite sign that you do a linebreak inmidst of a for loop expression.

Python is a language where whitespace is partly part of the syntax.
So you have to be hyper correct in terms of whitespaces/linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code:

```
alt_map = {'ins': '0'}
complement = {'A': 'T', 'C': 'G', 'G': 'C', 'T': 'A'}


def reverse_complement(seq):
    for k, v in alt_map.items():
        seq = seq.replace(k, v)
        bases = list(seq)
        bases = reversed([complement.get(base, base) for base in bases])
        bases = ''.join(bases)
        for k, v in alt_map.items():
            bases = bases.replace(v, k)
    return bases


if __name__ == '__main__':
    seq = 'TCGGinsGCCC'
    print(reverse_complement(seq))
```

Output:

```
GGGCinsCCGA
```